# UILabels are not displaying in my table view cells using contentView property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having an issue with `UILabels` not displaying in my table view cells using the contentView property of the cell. The `UILabels` were showing before I added a UIImage to the cells. I wanted to add the text to the cells and used cell.contenView so I could place the UILAbels where I wanted.

thanks for any help with this.

here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellReuseIdentifier = @"cellReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];


        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 30)];

        titleLabel.tag = 234234;
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN" size:24]];
        titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
        titleLabel.layer.shouldRasterize=YES;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

        UILabel *detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 160, cell.bounds.size.width, 30)];

        detailLabel.tag = 345345;
        detailLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DIN" size:18]];
        detailLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        detailLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
        detailLabel.layer.shouldRasterize=YES;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];

    }


    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:234234];
    titleLabel.text = (NSString *)[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    UILabel *detailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:345345];
    detailLabel.text = (NSString *)[[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];


    NSString *imageUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [self.imageCache objectForKey:imageUrlString];
    if (cachedImage)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = cachedImage;
    }
    else
    {

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest.jpg"]; // initialize the image with blank image as a placeholder

        // download in the image in the background

        [self.imageDownloadingQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

            NSURL *imageUrl   = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
            UIImage *image    = nil;
            if (imageData)
                image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            if (image)
            {

                [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:imageUrlString]; // add the image to your cache

                // finally, update the user interface in the main queue

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    // make sure the cell is still visible

                    UITableViewCell *updateCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    if (updateCell)
                        cell.imageView.image = image;
                }];
            }
        }];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

also, When I add     `cell.textLabel.text = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];`
instead of using the contentView the cell text displays off the the right.

[image]

Comment: May be the default imageview of cell is overlaying the labels.

Dont set image to that imageview and make the background color of imageview to clear color and then check whether the labels are displaying properly ?

Comment: @iUser I tried that and no uilabels appear still. When I add     cell.textLabel.text = [[publicDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
instead of using the contentView the cell text displays off the the right. I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just did a silly mistake over here:

```
detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

You're trying to show white font color on a white background?

I just tested your code like below and it displayed correctly:

```
UILabel *titleLabel;
UILabel *detailLabel;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellReuseIdentifier = @"cellReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];


        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 30)];

        titleLabel.tag = 234234;
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
        titleLabel.layer.shouldRasterize=YES;


        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

        detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 160, cell.bounds.size.width, 30)];

        detailLabel.tag = 345345;
        detailLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [detailLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        detailLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        detailLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
        detailLabel.layer.shouldRasterize=YES;
           [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];


      [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:titleLabel];
      [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:detailLabel];


         }



    detailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:345345];
    detailLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:234234];
    titleLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

To bring your created label above your image view you just need to add those two lines:

```
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:titleLabel];
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:detailLabel];
```

Also, add image contentView as seen below:

```
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 40 ,40)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgvie];
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks! You were right! I had the tablecell background color as clear color before but then removed it. I changed the color and it shows up now. The problem is that the uiimage is above the text now. Do I have to add the image using contentView instead of                         cell.imageView.image = image;
?